# chrome.extension sometimes undefined in background js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[EDIT]

I have reduced my failing code to a much smaller case.

See https://github.com/deg/tmp-chrome-extension-bug

This is a slightly modified copy of https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted, changed to include a content script and background page.

Even in this simple extension, chrome.runtime.id is sometimes undefined. It looks like a timing problem.

Instructions to reproduce are the repo readme.

[ORIGINAL TEXT]

I have a chrome extension with a background script "background.js"

In this file, at top level, I have chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(...);

I test by doing reload on the extension in chrome://extensions. This usually works, but sometimes chrome.runtime.onMessage is undefined.

In debugging, I've found that, whenever this happens, chrome.extension and chrome.runtime.id are also undefined.

I can make the problem "go away" by repeatedly hitting the reload button until it loads correctly.

I first noticed this problem recently, so assumed it was something I had broken.
But, after a session of git bisect and hair-pulling, I see that the problem was in even my earliest versions; just occurring much less frequently.

It looks like there is some timing problem at startup -- maybe something is not initialized until after my code has loaded. So, as my code gets longer, I'm seeing the problem more often.  (Just a guess)

What is the correct way to do chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener in the background. Does it need to be wrapped inside an onSomething? Examples I've seen also do it at top-level.  Confused!

Comment: I've never seen chrome.runtime.onMessage be undefined. However, I am using an eventPage which Google now recommends: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition. Have you tried that?

Comment: I think there might be something else wrong in your code because I've never seen this problem on a background page (`"persistent": true`) and I've reloaded extensions thousands of times.

Comment: have you tried wrapping on a basic `(function(){  ...  })();` ?

Comment: There's no need to wrap API calls.

Comment: Sounds like I must have done something stupid early on. I'll find some working sample, and will migrate it up to my code until I find what breaks.
I'm disappearing for the evening now, and will do this tomorrow.
If anyone has any insight meanwhile, I'm all ears.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, if I'm doing something stupid, it is VERY early on. I've created a minimal extension that shows the problem. See edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Tried your test case, and I cannot reproduce it. In any case, you're doing nothing wrong, and as such it's a bug that needs to be reported at https://crbug.com/ - perhaps the Chromium team can help reproduce it.

Comment: Also, important question: what version of Chrome / OS are you using?

Comment: About reports:
"Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit)
 Nearly up-to-date! Relaunch Google Chrome to finish updating."
On a Mac.

I'll try restarting soon, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Also reported now as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=565384

Comment: FWIW, problem still happening in "Version 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit)"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this problem is caused by a bad interaction with another extension I had loaded on my machine; probably Symantec's "Norton Security Toolbar". More details in the parallel discussion at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=565384