# Chrome extension: not all API's present after chrome.runtime.reload()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with my Chrome Extension that that depends on the
`chrome.tabs` API.

My extension is mostly running normally. Sometimes I do a
`chrome.runtime.reload()` and that works mostly without problems, but
now and then (I have neither been able to predict when or reliably
replicate it) when the background script comes back after the restart
the `chrome.tabs` reference is `undefined`. Since I depend on that API
the extension can't start. That scenario can be detected, but when I
try to do a `chrome.runtime.reload()`, `chrome.runtime.reload` is also
`undefined`. So then I don't have a method to restart again.

I realise that I probably ought to develop soft restart capabilities
for my extension to return to a blank state, but that's very work
intensive, so I wanted to ask the community if anyone else have any
experience with this problem, and in that case, how have you solved
it?

Here is my permissions from the `manifest.json` file:

```
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "contextMenus",
   "webNavigation",
   "webRequest",
   "webRequestBlocking",
   /* some whitelisted web URLs... */
```

Comment: I remember this being mentioned before, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045969/chrome-extension-sometimes-undefined-in-background-js

Comment: Good to know, but somewhat bad news since it points towards an open apparently difficult bug in Chromium. More weight to my theory of avoiding `chrome.runtime.reload()` and develop software restarts in the extension itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot [@Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan) for
pointing me towards [this
other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045969/chrome-extension-sometimes-undefined-in-background-js)
question that seems to cover the exact same phenomenon.

I have decided that enough indications point towards this being a bug
in chrome's handling of background pages.

I also have some additional observations:

- The question pointed to by @Xan have references to a likely bug in
  Chrome's background pages.
- When I replicated the bug by calling `chrome.runtime.reload()` in my
  background page's developer tools console I found that
  `chrome.runtime.reload()` was available as usual to my extension's
  popup UI.
- Background pages are not (yet) deprecated, but the first line in the
  [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)
  recommends migrating to event pages instead, they can't possibly be
  high on the Chromium team's priority list. In other words, I consider
  the risk of this bug - if it is one - to have a high risk of being
  categorized a `'wontfix'`, therefore, it looks unproductive to try
  to wait out a fix.

Therefore, I have devised a workaround that I think will be
satisfactory until I have the resources to either develop
soft-restart capabilities in my extension *OR* migrate to event pages:

Given that:

- Most of my extensions functionality is triggered via a Chrome
  `browserAction`. Before the browser action starts to render, I can
  post a message to the background page that I know will call back
  immediately.
- When the extension have started normally, the fix will simply be a
  no-op invisible to the end-user.
- Since the fix normal operation is a no-op the fix won't hurt the
  extension should the Chromium team fix the bug in a future release.
- "Dead" background pages will have failed to register *any* message
  listener. If the background page doesn't respond to the safety check
  message, the popup can fix the broken state by restarting the
  extension.

*This comes at a cost:* if the popup times out waiting for the 'safety
net' message and restarts, the popup UI will be brutally closed
without warning from under the end user's feet. Not nice - but after
some consideration I have decided that I think that behaviour is far
preferable to the extension just silently stopping working like it
can do now.

Comment if you have further ideas!

Comment: Background pages are not deprecated at all; it's just that event pages are more efficient. Could you try to create a minimal extension that triggers your bug in a new profile, and post it at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=565384? With a reproducible test case, it is easier to debug the problem and fix it on Chrome's side.

Comment: No, it's not deprecated but has a big red "Caution" at the top. In my experience software projects tend to avoid support on subsystem they don't recommend. Also, it's a good idea in principle, but my extension is large and I'm pressed for time. With a stop-gap fix for the worst symptom, I might be able to afford a more correct look at the problem later.

Comment: Your question shows the use of the webRequest API, which cannot be used with event pages yet: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447270. PS. I contribute to Chrome and this doesn't look like a WontFix bug, so if you provide a reliable test case, the bug may actually get fixed.

Comment: Ok, then it looks like it's going to be a question of development economics if I try to create a reproducible test case or not. I'll be watching out for alternatives to my user of webRequest a little closer in the future, too.